# MySQL Subquery Question

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query to pull a total number for a given publisher ID. I'd like to use it as a subquery so I can iterate over all publisher IDs.

My working query for a given ID is:

```
SELECT SUM( d.our_cost ) 
FROM articles a
CROSS JOIN domains d ON a.domain_id = d.id
    AND d.publisher_id =  '1094'
```

I'd like to pull this figure for all ID's in publisher p table where d.publisher_id = p.id

So far I've tried the following to no avail:

```
SELECT p.id, p.contact_name, p.contact_email, 
    (SELECT SUM(d.our_cost)
     FROM articles a
     CROSS JOIN domains d ON a.domain_id = d.id and d.publisher_id = p.id) total
FROM publishers p
```

The specific error I'm getting is:  Unknown column 'p.id' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify your query and put the subquery in the from clause, something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.contact_name, p.contact_email, total.total_cost
FROM 
  (
  SELECT SUM(d.our_cost) as total_cost, d.publisher_id 
  FROM articles a CROSS JOIN domains d ON a.domain_id = d.id ) total 
JOIN publishers p on total.publisher_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've gotten an error about your syntax, try:

```
SELECT p.id, p.contact_name, p.contact_email, SUM(d.our_cost) as total
FROM articles a
     CROSS JOIN domains d ON a.domain_id = d.id 
     JOIN publishers p ON d.publisher_id = p.id
```

Comment: Hmm, good advice, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. The error I'm getting is: Unknown column 'p.id' in 'on clause'.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a group by would be handy here instead

Also it seems like you dont need articles table at all (unless you have additional business rules)

```
SELECT p.id, p.contact_name, p.contact_email, IFNULL(SUM(d.our_cost),0) AS total
  FROM publishers p
  LEFT JOIN domains d ON d.publisher_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id
```